# Getting 'RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.' when trying to import function from another Blueprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

***Initial Notes:** The project uses Blueprints and below are the file structure and extracts of the code used...*

### **File Structure:**

```
/app
├── flaskapp/
│   ├── posts/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   ├── utils.py
│   ├── users/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   ├── utils.py
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── crons.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── users.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── models.py
├── run.py
```

---

### *posts/utils.py*

```
# Function to get all posts from DB

def get_all_posts():
    post = Post.query.order_by(Post.id.asc())
    return post
```

### users/routes.py

```
# Importing 'get_all_posts' function from 'posts/utils.py'

from flaskapp.posts.utils import get_all_posts



users = Blueprint('users', __name__)


#All Users Route + Related Posts

@posts.route("/posts", methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def all_users():
    users = User.query.order_by(User.id.asc())
    return render_template('users.html', USERS=users, POSTS=get_all_posts())
```

### main/crons.py

```
# Importing 'get_all_posts' function from 'posts/utils.py'

from flaskapp.posts.utils import get_all_posts


# A function to be called using 'scheduler' from 'flaskapp/__init__.py' on launch

def list_expired_posts():
    posts = get_all_posts()
    for p in posts:
        if p.expired == 1:
            print(p.title)

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=list_expired_posts, trigger="interval", seconds=60)
scheduler.start()


# Terminate Scheduler on APP termination

atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

### flaskapp/**init**.py

```
# __init__.py Main

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flaskapp.config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'warning'


# Create APP Function
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # Import Configuration from Config File Class
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    # Import Blueprint objects
    from flaskapp.posts.routes import posts
    from flaskapp.users.routes import users
    from flaskapp.main.routes import main
    
    # Register Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    # END

    return(app)

# Calling scheduler function 'list_expired_posts' FROM '/main/crons.py' as a scheduled job to be triggered on app initiation

from flaskapp.main.crons import list_expired_posts
list_expired_posts()
```

## Explanation:

I have the function '**get_all_posts()**' located in '**posts/utils.py**' which works fine when I import it and use it in another blueprint's **routes.py** file (***ex.***** users/routes.py**) as shown above.

But I'm getting the below error when importing the same function in another blueprint (***specifically.***** main/crons.py**) as shown above.

I'm trying to use the '**get_all_posts()**' function from '**posts/utils.py**' within the '**list_expired_posts()**' in '**main/crons.py**' and then calling the '**list_expired_posts()**' function from '**flaskapp/init.py**' to trigger it on launch and keep on executing it every 60 minutes.

### Error:

*RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.*

*This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed*
*the current application. To solve this, set up an application context*
*with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.*

***Conclusion Notes + Steps attempted:** *

*I have already eliminated the '**Scheduler**' temporarily and tried working only with the function itself and not even calling it from '**flaskapp/init.py**'.*

---

I have also tried moving the below code to the '**def create_app(config_class=Config)**' section without any luck

```
from flaskapp.main.crons import list_expired_posts
list_expired_posts()
```

---

I have also tried creating a specific Blueprint for '**crons.py**' and registering it to my '**flaskapp/init.py**' but still got the same result.

---

As a final outcome, I am trying to call the '**get_all_posts()**' FROM **'posts/utils.py**', then filter out the '**expired posts**' using the '**list_expired_posts()**' function FROM '**main/crons.py**' and schedule it to print the title of the expired posts every 60 minutes.

Since I've eliminated the scheduler already to test out, I'm quite sure this is not a scheduler issue but some import mixup I'm not figuring out.

---

I am also aware that the '**list_expired_posts()**' can become as another function in '**posts/utils.py**' and then directly call the function from there using the scheduler which I've also tried but keep getting the same error.

---

I also tried manually configuring the app's context as instructed in other posts but I keep getting the same error.

```
with app.app_context():
```

---

I'm not really a Python pro and I always try seeking multiple online resources prior to posting a question here but it seems like i'm out of luck this time. Your help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no blueprint in `crons.py`, which is expected as it's about scheduling, not routing.

Not being in a route, you get the error that the application context is missing, because effectively everything not in a route does not have an application context.

You might want to look into [Flask-APScheduler](https://viniciuschiele.github.io/flask-apscheduler/), which you'd initialise in a similar way to Flask-SQLAlchemy and then use in your `crons.py`, it should carry the application context transparently.

**PS.** In `users/routes.py` you define a `users` Blueprint, but them seem to use a `posts` blueprint in the route decorator.

Ok, sorry for delay but here is a demo of using Flask-SQLAlchemy and Flask-APSscheduler to access the app context from scheduled tasks.

```py
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
scheduler = APScheduler()

users = Blueprint("users", __name__)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Name %r>" % self.id


def get_all_users():
    return User.query.all()


@users.route("/all", methods=["GET"])
def handle_users_all():
    return get_all_users()


@scheduler.task("cron", id="job_get_all_users", second="*/10")
def scheduled_get_all_users():
    with scheduler.app.app_context():
        get_all_users()


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.register_blueprint(users)

    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////tmp/74975778.db"
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    app.config["SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED"] = True
    scheduler.init_app(app)
    scheduler.start()

    return app
```

**NB.** this does not do anything useful in the scheduled task, I leave it up to you, but it can execute the utility function `get_all_users` on schedule.

Comment: Cheers for this, honestly I don’t think it’s a scheduler related issue as I’ve eliminated the scheduler totally and tried calling the get_all_posts() function alone and still getting the same error. I would really appreciate your demo whenever possible. I’m sure it’ll help me refactor my structure properly. Cheers

Comment: If you call a function which relies on Flask-SQLAlchemy outside of the Flask context (be that a scheduler or calling the function on its own), you will be hit with `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`. Been unexpectedly busy, will try to get you a demo by tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't think this is directly related to the scheduler. I think it works in your `users/routes.py` because it is inside a route. So it will only get called when you visit that route. And by then your app is fully created and has its context and whatever.

But in main/crons.py it is not inside a route so I think it will try to run it when it passes this import line in your `flaskapp/init.py`

```
from flaskapp.main.crons import list_expired_posts
```

Maybe you could try this: putting the scheduler part into a function

#### main/crons.py

```
# Importing 'get_all_posts' function from 'posts/utils.py'

from flaskapp.posts.utils import get_all_posts


# A function to be called using 'scheduler' from 'flaskapp/__init__.py' on launch

def list_expired_posts():
    posts = get_all_posts()
    for p in posts:
        if p.expired == 1:
            print(p.title)


def initiate_scheduler():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func=list_expired_posts, trigger="interval", seconds=60)
    scheduler.start()
```

and then call that function in your run.py after you create the app

#### run.py

```
# first create the app
app = create_app()
# then start the scheduler
initiate_scheduler()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    # if you visit '/posts' in a browser it will call the get_all_posts() 
    # at this point in time after all the other code has ran.
```

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately, I keep getting the same issue… same I don’t think it’s scheduler related as I’ve eliminated the scheduler completely. Cheers for the help though. I’ll post an update if I ever find a solution